# How to know which folder/file is oldest and which one is the newest?

Tags: windows-10

I have many files inside a folder but I forgot to make versions of them. Now I would like to know which one I created first and then which one come next, etc. Is there a way in Windows 10 to do that and know which file was created first (in order)?